# How to code a select only one item from forEach loop and deselect others in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to select only one in forEach like radio in html but I don't now how

```
let selected = document.querySelectorAll("#selected")

selected.forEach((e) => {

    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
        e.classList.add("cardActive")
    })
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
        selected.classList.remove("cardActive")
    })
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldXfw.png)

Comment: you can use JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
let selected = document.querySelectorAll("#selected")
selected.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
        active = document.querySelectorAll(".cardActive")
        // Remove the cardActive class from everywhere
        active.forEach((e2) => {
            e2.classList.remove("cardActive")
        })
        e.classList.add("cardActive")
    })
})
```